# Can't connect to SMTP server with Java

Tags: java, email, ssl, smtp, jakarta-mail

I want to send an email from Java using the Java Mail API (javax.mail.*). I can access the SMTP-server via Thunderbird with the following settings:

- Server: math.uni-freiburg.de
- Port: 465
- Username: MY_USERNAME
- Authentification: password, normal
- Security: SSL/TLS

I know nothing else about the SMTP server.

With my code I always get the error: **Could not connect to SMTP host: math.uni-freiburg.de, port: 465, response: -1**

```
String SMTP_HOST = "math.uni-freiburg.de"
String SMTP_USER = "MY_USERNAME@math.uni-freiburg.de";
String SMTP_PASSWORD = "MY_PASSWORD";
String SMTP_PORT = "465";

final Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", SMTP_PORT);
props.put("mail.transport.protocol","smtp");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
//props.put("mail.ssl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.tls", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.checkserveridentity", "true");

final javax.mail.Authenticator auth = new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
   @Override
   public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
      return new PasswordAuthentication(SMTP_USER, SMTP_PASSWORD);
   }
};

Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);


Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("MY_USERNAME@math.uni-freiburg.de", "MY NAME"));
msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("asdfasdf@gmail.com", "asdf asdf"));
msg.setSubject("SUBJECT");
msg.setText("THE MESSAGE");
msg.saveChanges();
Transport.send(msg);
```

I already tried to change some of the properties but since I don't really know what they do this wasn't very successfull.

Any ideas what I could change?

Comment: If you are getting any exception please post the full stack trace.

Comment: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: math.uni-freiburg.de, port: 465, response: -1
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1922)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
 at smtpTest.Email.send(Email.java:102)

Comment: I believe there is more...`caused by ..` section

Comment: That's all I get with e.printStackTrace();

Comment: Can you ping the host from your computer? Are you behind a corporate firewall?

Comment: Since port 465 is SMTPS it will expect the SSL handshake immediatly and will not expect a STARTTLS command to upgrade a plain connection. Thus `mail.smtp.starttls.enable` should be false. Also, `mail.smtp.ssl.enable` should be true.

Comment: Thanks, it is working now! props.put("mail.transport.protocol","smtps");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");

Comment: The "mail.transport.protocol" setting is having no effect, you can remove it.  You can further simplify your code by removing the Authenticator as described [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).